# How to disable work Outlook notifications until the next morning?

Tags: notifications, outlook

Just installed my working Outlook on my phone and now I want to disable the notifications for this app until tomorrow, 9:30 in the morning. I really do not need to be notified for every email that someone sends me after business hours. However, the problem is that the maximum time I can snooze the notifications for seems to be 2 hours.

How can I disable them for a longer period?

Answer (score 1):

I think the [Android Work profile](https://support.google.com/work/android/answer/6191949?hl=en) is a perfect solution for this case.

First you would need to set it up such that your work Outlook account (and app) is under your work profile. After that you can [schedule your work profile](https://www.xda-developers.com/pause-work-profile-schedule/) to "pause" at certain times.

When your work profile is paused, it will not send any notifications.

Comment: This will work, but the problem is that it seems that I should allow explicitly, every new app that I install to bug me in that work profile, and this is a work around that I  want to avoid.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean... Do you mean that you need to install each app that you want in the work profile separately (next to the personal profile)?

Comment: Not to install, but to click it from the list and thus to allow it

Comment: Maybe your work profile is different from mine, but I don't need to click anything individually. All my apps in the work profile (Gmail, calendar, WhatsApp) are automatically deactivated every day at 19:00 by the work profile schedule. I then stop receiving notifications from the work apps. The next day at 8 in the morning the work profile schedule starts all work apps again and I receive any missed notifications. Note that my personal apps (e. g. also Gmail and WhatsApp, but with a different account) are unaffected, I keep receiving notifications for them.

Comment: The idea is that for every new app that I install, I have to manually add it in the work profile, if I want to be getting messages from it and this is the workaround I do not like.